# Hive:How to back/front propagate a column value in SQL

Tags: sql, hiveql

```
A       B        C
apple   Fruit    GG
banana  Fruit    MM

Table T2:

Z        A           B                 C 
INIT     eggplant    Vegetable          TT
INIT     spinach     Vegetable          JJ
```

I need to union these two tables(T1 and T2) and create table T3 and back propagate the value of column Z to the rows from the other Table(T1) :
Output Should be:

```
Table T3

Z       A             B           C
INIT     eggplant    Vegetable          TT
INIT     spinach     Vegetable          JJ
INIT      apple       Fruit             GG
INIT      banana      Fruit             MM
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this if you can have many `Z` values:

```
select Z,A,B,C 
from T2
union all
select Z,A,B,C 
from T1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Z
    FROM T2
) DS
WHERE A IS NOT NULL
```

Can you try this, too:

```
select Z,A,B,C 
from T2
union all
select (select distinct z from T2),A,B,C 
from T1
```

Comment: I will try this out but not sure if "Cross Apply" works in Hive QL

Comment: @user2717470 Can you try `CROSS JOIN` then?

Comment: Thanks Will Do and  update here .I need to check if disbaling cross.join flag has any adverse effects on performance.

Comment: @user2717470 you said that the `INIT` can be any value, but can you tell if it is only one value? if it's only one it can be get in more better way.

Comment: Yes , it will only be one value (but that value can be dynamic) .All the values in Z column of T2 will have the same value

Comment: @user2717470 Can you try the second variant?

Comment: Even in the first solution , Not sure how you are using Z from  T1 as the table does not have the column